# D3 line consists of multiple segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I drew a line according to the following code:
Beneath the x and y scales are created

```
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, data.length - 1])
  .range([this.margin.left, contentWidth]);

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
  .range([20, 0]);
```

a simple scale that goes from 0 to data.length - 1 and the other one calculates the max of the data.

```
const apLineBottom = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(data.indexof(d))
  .y(d => (contentHeight / 2) + y(d.value));

const apLineTop = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(data.indexof(d))
  .y(d => (contentHeight / 2) - 10 - y(d.value));
```

Next up are the lines, I want them to be in the middle parallel to each other (going up and down according to the given data).

```
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", apLineBottom(data))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", apLineTop(data))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

Next I add them to the svg which results in the following result:
This is not what I want since stuff is sticking out. Am I missing something to smooth the curve?

For reference: the image only contains the bottom line.

[image: example]

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQjlh.png)

Comment: What data is being fed to this? Maybe this will help regarding the line smoothing part: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529

Comment: without seeing an actual runnable example, I'd take a guess that culprit is `x(data.indexof(d))` -- this would only work if your line is bijective, otherwise you'll get wrong index for repeatedly appearing data